# can you parse a json field into a single column with multiple rows instead of multiple column - POSTGRES

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a json field that includes the id's of up to 9 different agents.There is also a singular leadID in the json field. My current setup is to parse the json field into a column for each agent id listed, but ideally I would like to make it one column for the 9 agents but up to 9 rows for the leadID.
ex.

| leadID | agent id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 |
| 1 | 1567 |
| 1 | 1789 |
| 1 | 1002 |
| 1 | 18345 |

my current query to parse the json field is:

```
SELECT cast(_airbyte_data->>'leadId' as bigint) as lead_id,
    _airbyte_data->'agents'->0->>'aggregateId' as agent1,
    _airbyte_data->'agents'->1->>'aggregateId' as agent2,
    _airbyte_data->'agents'->2->>'aggregateId' as agent3,
    _airbyte_data->'agents'->3->>'aggregateId' as agent4,
    _airbyte_data->'agents'->4->>'aggregateId' as agent5,
    _airbyte_data->'agents'->5->>'aggregateId' as agent6,
    _airbyte_data->'agents'->6->>'aggregateId' as agent7,
    _airbyte_data->'agents'->7->>'aggregateId' as agent8,
    _airbyte_data->'agents'->8->>'aggregateId' as agent9,
    _airbyte_data
from agent_list

)
,
agent_name_cte AS (
    select apc.*,
    concat(pup.first_name,' ',pup.last_name) as agent_name_1,
    concat(pup2.first_name,' ',pup2.last_name) as agent_name_2,
    concat(pup3.first_name,' ',pup3.last_name) as agent_name_3,
    concat(pup4.first_name,' ',pup4.last_name) as agent_name_4,
    concat(pup5.first_name,' ',pup5.last_name) as agent_name_5,
    concat(pup6.first_name,' ',pup6.last_name) as agent_name_6,
    concat(pup7.first_name,' ',pup7.last_name) as agent_name_7,
    concat(pup8.first_name,' ',pup8.last_name) as agent_name_8,
    concat(pup9.first_name,' ',pup9.last_name) as agent_name_9
    from agent_pool_cte apc
    left join partner_user_profiles pup on pup.aggregate_id::text = apc.agent1
    left join partner_user_profiles pup2 on pup2.aggregate_id::text = apc.agent2
    left join partner_user_profiles pup3 on pup3.aggregate_id::text = apc.agent3
    left join partner_user_profiles pup4 on pup4.aggregate_id::text = apc.agent4
    left join partner_user_profiles pup5 on pup5.aggregate_id::text = apc.agent5
    left join partner_user_profiles pup6 on pup6.aggregate_id::text = apc.agent6
    left join partner_user_profiles pup7 on pup7.aggregate_id::text = apc.agent7
    left join partner_user_profiles pup8 on pup8.aggregate_id::text = apc.agent8
    left join partner_user_profiles pup9 on pup9.aggregate_id::text = apc.agent9
)
select * from agent_name_cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Without table DDL, sample data, and an example expected result, it's impossible to be sure if the following fully addresses your question.

```
WITH agent_pool_cte AS (SELECT (_airbyte_data ->> 'lead_id')::bigint                                       AS lead_id,
                               (JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(_airbyte_data -> 'agents') ->> 'aggregate_id')::bigint AS agent_id
                          FROM agent_list),
     agent_name_cte AS (SELECT apc.*,
                               CONCAT(pup.first_name, ' ', pup.last_name) AS agent_name
                          FROM agent_pool_cte apc
                            LEFT JOIN partner_user_profiles pup
                                      ON pup.aggregate_id = apc.agent_id)
SELECT *
  FROM agent_name_cte;
```

Because `pup.aggregate_id` was being cast to `text` in the SQL you presented, I assume that it is actually a numeric. In the where clause, casting types of columns for tables that are being searched will usually prevent using an index.